# Shell scripting : Find file with the name 'error_log' and check sizes, remove if over a certain size

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to create a shell script/command that find error_log files created by PHP, check their file sizes and remove them if over a certain size.

I have only gotten as far as printing the files and file sizes with the code below

```
for i in `locate -r 'error_log$'`;do echo "$i|" `stat -c %s $i`;done
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
find $DIR -type f -name error_log -size +${BYTES_MIN}c -print0 |xargs -0 rm
```

For example:

```
find . -type f -name error_log -size +500k -print0 |xargs -0 rm
```

This will quietly remove any error log file anywhere under the current directory and larger than 500k (c for bytes, k for kilobytes, M for megabytes, ...). If you wish to see the destruction done then add `-v` to `rm`.

Comment: Substitute ` |xargs -0 rm` with ` -delete` and we have a winner.

Comment: Thank you Wilhelm, but can it be done with 'locate'?
Find will take a long time to traverse into hundreds of thousands of folders.

Comment: Did you ever find an efficient solution to this issue?  I have the same and would love a quick & effective approach to solving it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate), but that presupposes that you know where the log files are. I wouldn't use `locate` since that uses a database that may be stale or even not updated at all.

Comment: We can't use logrotate because this error_log file is not the apache error_log that is usually found in the /logs/ directory but it is present in hundreds of directories and is created whenever a PHP script in that directory runs into some kind of errors, even harmless ones. And let's assume that we are not allowed to turn the error_log file generation feature in PHP. 

Anyway locate is the right tool for the job as my server is a cPanel server, it updates the locate DB probably once a week anyway.
And I plan to run this cleanup script once every 2 weeks.